# How can i get a deformable object's gemetric pose(position, orientation) or frame?

Tags: drake

We are making a simulation environment with deformable objects using pydrake. Now, we want to move the deformable object with our joysticks or keyboard (not decided yet) to desired positions in Runtime.

We refer to this example : https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/f561342ef0498666a519b57d36d3b9c15bf8e12d/examples/multibody/deformable_torus/deformable_torus.cc

After following the example, we got a diagram.

In the multibody plant we created, applied_generalized_force, actuation, and **_desired_state input ports are disabled unlike other rigidbody object examples.

How can we control the state(position, velocity, force) of the deformable object?

Comment: Deformable bodies don't have the same properties as rigid bodies. Drake uses the convention that the deformable state is always measured and expressed in the world frame, and that state is the position and velocities of the individual nodes of the deformable mesh. Is that what you had in mind? Or were you hoping for a sense of the instantaneous position/velocity of its center of mass?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We were hoping to get the position or velocity of the point that represent the object (like center of mass), not the individual nodes. Is there a way to know this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Right now deformable bodies are not actuated. They only react to external forces (e.g. gravity, contact or fixed constraint, user defined external force field) and internal stress induced by deformation. You can get the positions of the individual nodes and take an average to obtain a crude estimate of the center of mass. It's not clear to me what exactly you are looking to achieve so I can't tell whether the position and velocity of the center of mass is the right thing to query about. If there's a legitimate use case of the center of mass, open a github issue and we can support it.